# Ranking of values in one quarter

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to implement a calculation that will rank the Price values in a separate partition. Below you can see my data

```
df<-data.frame( year=c(2010,2010,2010,2010,2010,2010),
                quarter=c("q1","q1","q1","q2","q2","q2"),
                Price=c(10,20,30,10,20,30)
                )

df
```

Now I want to count over each quarter and I expect to have 1 for the smallest Price and 3 for the highest Price

```
  df %>% group_by(quarter) %>% mutate(id = row_number(Price))
```

Instead of the expected results, I received different results. Below you can see the result from the code. Instead of ranking in separate `quarter`, ranging is in both quarters.

[image]

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and to receive results as in table below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `rank`.

```
transform(df, id=ave(Price, year, quarter, FUN=rank))
#   year quarter Price id
# 1 2010      q1    10  1
# 2 2010      q1    20  2
# 3 2010      q1    30  3
# 4 2010      q2    10  1
# 5 2010      q2    20  2
# 6 2010      q2    30  3
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I need. In the second table, you can see what I expect to get

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, use `dense_rank`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(quarter) %>% 
  mutate(id = dense_rank(Price)) %>% 
  ungroup
# A tibble: 6 × 4
   year quarter Price    id
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <int>
1  2010 q1         10     1
2  2010 q1         20     2
3  2010 q1         30     3
4  2010 q2         10     1
5  2010 q2         20     2
6  2010 q2         30     3
```

---

In the newer version of `dplyr`, can also use `.by` in `mutate`

```
df %>%
  mutate(id = dense_rank(Price), .by = 'quarter')
   year quarter Price id
1 2010      q1    10  1
2 2010      q1    20  2
3 2010      q1    30  3
4 2010      q2    10  1
5 2010      q2    20  2
6 2010      q2    30  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively with `row_number()`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(year, quarter) %>% mutate(id=row_number())
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   year, quarter [2]
   year quarter Price    id
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <int>
1  2010 q1         10     1
2  2010 q1         20     2
3  2010 q1         30     3
4  2010 q2         10     1
5  2010 q2         20     2
6  2010 q2         30     3
```